# How to Change a Font Class Name Inside a Link With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the font class name after clicking the link with Javascript and jQuery.

**The button example:**

```
<a class='pe-1' onclick='change(this, 24)'><i class='bx bx-bookmark'></i></a>
```

If I try this way below will change the class from the link instead of the class from the font...

**Function example 1:**

```
function change(button, id) {

var changeButton = $(button);

changeButton.removeClass("bx-bookmark").addClass("bxs-bookmark");

}
```

Unfortunately doing the basic way (like my example below) doesn't really work for me since is going to change the value from all posts instead of just that one post.

**Function example 2:**

```
function change(button, id) {

var changeButton = $(button);

$(".bx").removeClass("bx-bookmark").addClass("bxs-bookmark");

}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally use `$(this).find('bx').removeClass("bx-bookmark").addClass("bxs-bookmark");` to find the child within the link clicked

Here's a way you could do it without the `onclick` attribute in the html
and I even made it a toggle :-)

```html
<a class='pe-1'><i class='bx bx-bookmark'></i></a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // on any .pe-1 click
    $('.pe-1').click(function(){

        // find the child with the class .bx
        target = $(this).find('.bx');

        // if it has class bx-bookmark
        if (target.hasClass('bx-bookmark')){
            // remove it and add bxs-bookmark
            target
                .removeClass("bx-bookmark")
                .addClass("bxs-bookmark");
        }else{
            // we assume it has bxs-bookmark already
            //  so swap it back
            target
                .removeClass("bxs-bookmark")
                .addClass("bx-bookmark");
        };
    });

});
```

I wasn't sure what **id** was for so I removed it. If that's important just let me know what it's for and I'll figure out a solution.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much Nealium